# Schedule Page/CPT Revisions

Tags: revisions

I'm currently working on a wordpress installation that (ab-)uses wordpress Pages with extensive ammounts of custom fields to allow for simple handling of landingpages etc.

Our users now asked for a simple solution that allows them to schedule changes to published wordpress for specific dates in the future.

is there any plugin or wordpress functionality that enables this kind of behavior?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Interesting question, but I think it is off topic (plugin recomendation) or too broad.

Comment: @G-M is correct. This is off topic (plugin recomendation) or too broad. What kind of changes need to be scheduled? And under what conditions?

Comment: we would like to schedule every changes made to an already published page, e.g. 'normal' content as well as all postmeta (custom fields)